# VBA to Transfer Range of Cells with Merge & Grouping

Tags: vba, excel

Not sure how to put this in words, but basically macro is run from the sheet1 of WorkBook1, and it should produce one like sheet1 of WorkBook2. (WB2 Sheet1 is empty)

The trick is that macro should only work with user selected range.
So if A1:A7 is selected, it will only grab data from A1:A7 to last column with data
If nothing is selected then exit sub with msgbox or something

Order/sort does not matter as long as it merges XYs duplicates and group respective fruits together.

```
   A      B      =>     A     B      C
1 XY3   Apple    =>  1  H    XY1    
2 XY1   Orange   =>  2  D          Orange
3 XY3   Banana   =>  3  H    XY2   
4 XY3   Banana   =>  4  D          Orange
5 XY3   Peach    =>  5  H    XY3      
6 XY4   Orange   =>  6  D          Apple
7 XY2   Orange   =>  7  D          Banana
8 XY7   Apple    =>  8  D          Banana
                 =>  9  D          Peach
                 => 10  H    XY4    
                 => 11  D          Orange
 [WB1 Sheet1]    =>      [WB2 Sheet1]
```

This might be difficult but I am desperately seeking for help.
Thank you so much!

Comment: There is always at least one cell selected in Excel.  Do you want to ignore any single cells ranges instead?

Comment: Yes users can select one or multiple rows From A1 or A1+.
And they know to make a selection before running the macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up this macro to copy to sheet2 of the same workbook.  To save to a new workbook just update the following line of code with your workbook name instead of activeworkbook.

```
Set sheetB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
```

Started with the following data in sheet 1 and a blank sheet 2:

[image]

Select A1 to A8 and run this macro:

```
Sub CopyAndFormat()
  If IsEmpty(Selection) Then
    MsgBox ("Empty Cell")
    Exit Sub
  End If
    
  Dim sheet As Worksheet
  Set sheetA = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set sheetB = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

  Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long
  FirstRow = Selection.Rows(1).Row
  LastRow = Selection.Rows.Count + FirstRow - 1

  'First Column
  Dim rngA As Range
  Set rngA = Range("A" & FirstRow & ":A" & LastRow)
  Dim datA As Variant
  datA = rngA
  Dim i As Long

  'Second Column Match
  Dim rngB As Range
  Set rngB = Range("B" & FirstRow & ":B" & LastRow)
  Dim datB As Variant
  datB = rngB
  Dim j As Long

  Dim resultA As Variant
  Dim resultB As Variant
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim rngr As Range

  Set rng = sheetB.Range("A1:A" & LastRow + 100)
  Set rngr = sheetB.Range("B1:B" & LastRow + 100)
  resultA = rng
  resultB = rngr

  'Store duplicates
  Dim rngString As String
  rngString = "empty"
  Dim match As Boolean
  match = False
  Dim cntr As Integer
  cntr = 1

  'First Column loop
  For i = LBound(datA, 1) To UBound(datA, 1)
    If rngString <> "empty" Then
        If Not Intersect(Range("A" & i), Range(rngString)) Is Nothing Then
            GoTo nextloop
        End If
    End If
    
    'Second Column Loop
    For j = LBound(datA, 1) + i To UBound(datA, 1)
        If i <> j And datA(i, 1) = datA(j, 1) And Not IsEmpty(datA(j, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(datA(i, 1)) Then
            'copy position of duplicate in variant
            If rngString = "empty" Then
                match = True
                resultA(cntr, 1) = datA(i, 1)
                resultB(cntr + 1, 1) = datB(i, 1)
                resultB(cntr + 1, 1) = datB(i, 1)
                resultB(cntr + 2, 1) = datB(j, 1)
                
                rngString = "A" & i & ",A" & j
                cntr = cntr + 2
            Else
                resultB(cntr + 1, 1) = datB(j, 1)
                cntr = cntr + 1
                
                rngString = rngString & "," & "A" & j
            End If
        End If
        
        
    Next
    
    If match = False Then
        resultA(cntr + 1, 1) = datA(i, 1)
        resultB(cntr + 2, 1) = datB(i, 1)
        cntr = cntr + 2
    End If
        
    match = False
    'cntr = cntr + 1
nextloop:
  Next

  rng = resultA
  rngr = resultB
End Sub
```

You'll get the following on sheet2:

[image]

Sorry the code is a little messy and I hate using goto's but this will get you started.